# Files inside Docker container not updating when I edit in host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Docker which is running fine.
I can start a Docker image using docker-compose.

```
docker-compose rm nodejs; docker-compose rm db; docker-compose up --build
```

I attached a shell to the Docker container using

```
docker exec -it nodejs_nodejs_1 bash
```

I can view files inside the container

```
(inside container)
cat server.js
```

Now when I edit the `server.js` file inside the host, I would like the file inside the container to change without having to restart Docker.
I have tried to add `volumes` to the `docker-compose.yml` file or to the Dockerfile, but somehow I cannot get it to work.

```
(Dockerfile, not working)
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
VOLUMES ["/usr/src/app"]

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "watch" ]
```

or

```
(docker-compose.yml, not working)
version: "3.3"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: ./nodejs-server
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
    links:
      - db:db
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
    volumes:
      - src: /usr/src/app
  db:
    build: ./mysql-server
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-server/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d #A folder /mysql-server/data with a .sql file needs to exist
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
volumes:
  src:
```

There is probably a simple guide somewhere, but I havn't found it yet.

Comment: use volumes in compose file like this:  ./path/to/application:/usr/src/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a copy of the files to be visible in the container, use a bind mount volume (aka host volume) instead of a named volume.

Assuming your docker-compose.yml file is in the root directory of the location that you want in /usr/src/app, then you can change your docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: ./nodejs-server
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
    links:
      - db:db
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  db:
    build: ./mysql-server
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-server/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d #A folder /mysql-server/data with a .sql file needs to exist
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
```

Comment: In my case the location that I want in ```/usr/src/app``` is in the sub-folder ```nodejs-server```. I changed your line ```- .:/usr/src/app``` to ```- ./nodejs-server:/usr/src/app``` and it works :-)